# NEXUS npm install giving 403 error

Tags: nexus, npm-install

I am trying to use a private repository via Nexus for npm . My build server and nexus server is behind a coporate proxy. When i am accessing public registry npm using proxy install is working fine. But when I try using private registry I am getting 403. I suspect that the issue is with authentication but I have tried both npm login and npm adduser with no effect. Also tried enabling Anonymus access but with no use. getting the same 403 error. I have also set proxy in the nexus.

Comment: Hi @Amol did you find a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're running into one or both of these issues:

- https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-12456
- https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-12022

If that looks right, I'd suggest following them (and voting if you feel inclined) for future updates.